# Adding multiple criteria to LDAP searches

Tags: c#, .net, ldap

I have functioning example code to query all users that match a certain department number and echo all associated LDAP properties for each user:

```
string attribute = "departmentnumber";
string value = "123";

DirectoryEntry rootEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://ldap.acme.com:389");
rootEntry.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.None;

DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(rootEntry, $"({attribute}={value})");

SearchResultCollection results = searcher.FindAll();

foreach (SearchResult result in searcher.FindAll())
{
    var allLDAPProperties = result.Properties.PropertyNames;

    foreach (var property in allLDAPProperties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((result.Properties[property.ToString()].Count > 0 ? result.Properties[property.ToString()][0] : string.Empty).ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

However, I would like to add multiple criterion to my initial search (e.g. Return all users with a "departmentnumber" attribute matching "123" and a "joblevel" attribute matching "5." I'm unable to find the correct way to supply compound filter criteria to `DirectorySearcher`.

I know I could filter the initial result set down with additional processing in a `foreach` loop, but I'm trying to be efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to specify multiple search criteria for an LDAP search, you need to use the [LDAP search filter syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adsi/search-filter-syntax) (described in full detail in the linked documentation).

Basically, if you want two criteria, your search filter would be something like:

```
(&(departmentnumber=123)(joblevel=5))
```

Check the linked documentation for a full explanation and more examples.